# how to sortby a given value a generic type list

Tags: c#, linq, list, generics

What I am trying to do is this code

```
filtered = GetUserList().OrderBy(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

in a generic way

```
public static List<T> sortBy<T>(string field, List<T>list)
{
    //list.OrderBy(p=>p.Equals(field)).ToList();
    //list = list.OrderBy(p => p.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().Find(d => d.Name.Equals(field))).ToList();
    return list;
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What is the problem with what you have?

Comment: `generic` might be the wrong term here. Judging by your code you are trying to order a list by a property passed as a string.

Comment: i need to sort by a given value (field) but its different each time so i need to make it in a generic way. so i tried to create  sortBy method for this perpose but it doesn't work

Comment: yes exactly ManfredRadlwimmer thats the point

Comment: I've come across a very similar (although slightly more complicated) case, I've linked it as a duplicate. With the code provided there you should be able to find a solution for this specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your **only** requirement, a quick way (instead of the more complicated one I linked) would be to access the properties by reflection. This extension method will give you the basics of what you need:

```
public static class EnumerablePropertyAccessorExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, string property)
    {
        return enumerable.OrderBy(x => GetProperty(x, property));
    }

    private static object GetProperty(object o, string propertyName)
    {
        return o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(o, null);
    }
}
```

[Example on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/VcRCS1)

Or (slightly optimized) like this:

```
public static class EnumerablePropertyAccessorExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, string property)
    {
        var prop = typeof(T).GetProperty(property);
        return enumerable.OrderBy(x => GetProperty(x, prop));
    }

    private static object GetProperty(object o, PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return property.GetValue(o, null);
    }
}
```

[Example on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/xpKwuD)

This extension method can then be called on any `IEnumerable<>` like this:

```
filtered = GetUserList().OrderBy("Name").ToList();
```

---

Note however, that this implementation is not really optimized or error-proofed. You might want to get to that if this is what you need.

Comment: Nice and simple solution!